# Slow PHP login form

Tags: php, security, authentication, mysqli

I am making a login information form but the loading of the form itself takes a long time (1-2 sec), so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.
I am also very worried about the security of this particular approach.

Thanks for any help whatsoever!

```
<?
        if(isset($_POST['send']))
        {
            $connection=mysqli_connect('host','user','password','database');

            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];

            $query=mysqli_prepare($connection,'SELECT access FROM users_table WHERE email=? AND password=?');   
            mysqli_bind_param($query,'ss',$email,$password);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$access);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);

            if($access>=0)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
                $_SESSION['user_password']=$password;
                $_SESSION['user_access']=$access;

                switch($access)
                {
                    case(0):
                        header('Location:admin page');
                    case(1):
                        header('Location:user page');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Wrong Password!';
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($query);

            mysqli_close($connection);
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <div id='login'>
                    <form method='POST' action=''>
                        <input name='email' type='email' placeholder='Enter your email...'>
                        <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='and your password.'>
                        <input class='button' name='send' type='submit' value='Send'>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <?
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I would not store password in text plain and more I wouldn't store it in the session

Comment: Do you try it on localhost or web server? And about security, you store password as plaintext, and save it to session for no reason.

Comment: You're not checking your MySQL calls for errors. Any failure will probably crash your app, but you won't know why.

Comment: I meant to add MD5 after but I kinda forgot. XD It ran on both local and server, with similar results. Thanks for the session tip, I will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottleneck is probably from the MySQL connection (is the MySQL server located remotely from the web server?)

You can find this out by saving a timestamp (using `microtime()`) before and after the `mysqli_connect` function, then subtracting end-start to get the total time.

Example:

```
$t = microtime(true);
// do connection here
die(microtime(true) - $t);
```

Comment: You were right, it was just the server acting up. :S

Comment: Lots of trolls around